# why the infinite radius of convergence results in that they are analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I'm reading the book, functions of one complex variable, John B. Conway.
in chapter 3.2, page 38, it is written that each of the series $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ has an infinite radius of convergence, and so they are analytic in $C$.

I can't understand why the infinite radius of convergence results in that they are analytic.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the given definition of analytic?

Comment: What is the definition of an analytic function?

Comment: $f: G \rightarrow C $ is analytic if $f$ is continuously differentiable on $G$ .@saulspatz

Answer (score 1):

You should use this terminology (you can use different words but the point is to use those concepts) :

- Analytic : represented by a power series on some disk around each point,
- Entire : represented by a single power series on the whole complex plane (the Taylor series at $z=0$ or at any point)
- Holomorphic : complex differentiable on some disk around each point.

The main theorem is the Cauchy integral theorem/formula which proves that holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}$ implies analytic on $\Bbb{C}$ and entire.

The same works for disks : holomorphic on a disk implies analytic and represented by a single power series (the Taylor series at the center of the disk).

The converse is obvious : entire implies analytic and holomorphic.

Comment: thanks for your help!